# Show all results of a table and how many are in which district

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table with records of cars. I want to query that table so that all (found) records are retrieved AND a table with the district-name plus how many cars are in the districts is shown besides the results.

Like a normal craigslist result page or similiar sites, where the results are shown, and on the left side is a table which shows where (in which disctrict, etc.) the results are and how many in each district are, etc.

At the moment I achieve that with two queries, but I asked me if that couldn't be done with just one query?

My table looks simplified like that:

```
    name | color | year | district
    ------------------------------
    ford | blue  | 1998 | 1010
    opel | red   | 2001 | 1030
    vw   | green | 1999 | 1010
    ...  | ...   | ...  | ...
```

So the result should look like:

```
districts       results
---------       ----------
1010 (2)        ford, 1998
1030 (1)        opel, 2001
....            vw, 1999
                ...
```

Hope you know what I mean.

Comment: What's the structure of the table that holds the districts?

Comment: What do you want the result set to look like?

Comment: To have two result sets, you need 2 queries.

Comment: Is one query what you want? It may be more efficient to do two.

Comment: that was not the answer i wanted to hear but if it's not possible, than it's not possible :) at the moment i'm retrieving my expected result with two queries, but i asked myself if that could not be done with a special "join-group-having" trick, because i query the same table two times... but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't generate two views from a single query. If you want to view all records, that's one query. If you want to view records grouped by district, that's a separate query.

Comment: that was not the answer i wanted to hear but if it's not possible, than it's not possible :) at the moment i'm retrieving my expected result with two queries, but i asked myself if that could not be done with a special "join-group-having" trick, because i query the same table two times... but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two result sets generated from one query.

To get the district name with the total number of cars do this:

```
SELECT d.name, COUNT(c.id) as total
FROM districts AS d
LEFT JOIN cars AS c ON c.district = d.id
GROUP BY d.id;
```

Comment: that was not the answer i wanted to hear but if it's not possible, than it's not possible :) at the moment i'm retrieving my expected result with two queries, but i asked myself if that could not be done with a special "join-group-having" trick, because i query the same table two times... but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have to use GROUP BY for this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

```sql
SELECT c.name, 
       c.color, 
       c.year, 
       c.district, 
       COUNT(c.id) counted,
FROM   cars c
GROUP BY district, name
```

Comment: thanks. but you're right and wrong. right for group by (for the districts), but wrong because if i make a group by i can't display _all_ of my cars (just grouped by the district) :)